# How to use Terraform to install AV when deploying a Windows AMI

Tags: windows, amazon-ami, terraform

Very first time I am using Terraform and I would like to know if its possible to install AV from a Terraform script or even set Powershell to remote execute?

Cheers, M

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could install a VM and as part of the setup install anti-virus. You can find examples of how to create a VM in Azure [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html).

Then you can use the provider to upload a PowerShell script to be executed, or run commands in-line etc. May options available. But it really requires some learning to get started ;-)